# DjangoRestFramework ParserError "Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, fetch, multipartform-data

#### Frontend

```html
<body>
  <input id="fileRef" type="file" />
  <button onclick="push">Push</button>

  <script>
    function push() {
      const file = fileRef.files[0];
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('image', file, file.name);

      fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/item/', {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

#### Backend

```py
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser

class ItemViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    ...
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]
```

The above is the minimal implementation of the bug, when I send the request, it will generate such an error: `Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None`

#### Request headers, payload

[image]

[image]

I spend a long time and don't know how to solve ;)

I tried change Content-Type like this

`'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'`

But it doesn't work, My expectation is that django can correctly parse and successfully accept the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it was a problem with django at first, but then I found out that my request on the front end was incorrect ;)

**WebAPI `fecth`, when sending `multipart/form-data`, there is no need to manually set the `Content-Type` attribute in request headers!!!**

If the request body is `FormData`, the browser will automatically add `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` to the headers and add the correct boundary.

I found this while browsing through these [articles](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/34291688), anyway, my problem was solved successfully~

I’m here to reply to a question I asked before, maybe someone will come here with the same question as me in the near future, hahahahaha...